# Identifying input tag in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

In my file upload servlet, I have 4 input tags as follows

```
<li>Left File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li><li><br></li>
<li>Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li><li><br></li>
<li>Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li><li><br></li>
<li>final File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile4" id="fileChooser4" /></li><li><br></li>
<li><button type="button" id="execute" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button></li>
```

Now, in my upload.java I want to identify which file from which input is being uploaded.

I've tried using,

```
String file1 = request.getParameter("dataFile1").toString();
String file2 = request.getParameter("dataFile2").toString();
String file3 = request.getParameter("dataFile3").toString();
String file4 = request.getParameter("dataFile4").toString();
```

and

```
if (file1 != null)
{
  //use apache commons and upload file
  out.println("left file uploaded");
}
```

But this does not work.

How to identify from which input tag the file is being uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the way you deal with file uploads

Maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932478/75554)

The relevant part is that [ServletFileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html) and [FileItem](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) from apache commons-fileupload is used, in turn FileItem has a method to get the [field name](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getFieldName%28%29).

Here is some sample code (from the answer linked above):

```
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items = null;
    try {
        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        if (item.isFormField()) {
        } else {
            try {
                String itemName = item.getName();
                String itemField = item.getFieldName();
                if (itemField.equals("datafile1")) {
                    // do things for left side
                } else if (itemField.equals("datafile2")) {
                    // do things for right side
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to distinctly identify which file is being uploaded based on the input tag description.

Comment: @Zedai you mean the label? labels aren't sent in the POST data, if you mean the input name/id then that link should give you what you need

Comment: See for example, if a left file is being uploaded I need to perform some operations on it and say if a right file is being uploaded then I need to perform a different set of operations on it. I know it man that labels aren't sent in POST, that is why I've tried with input tag name.

Comment: @Zedai, i know what you mean, as i said use FileItem.getFieldName to know which field the uploaded file belonged to and do your operations.