# How to update multiple records in database using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

## **EditableFormat.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@page import ="techpanel.Getters" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.Vector" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Panel Details</title>
</head>

<%Vector<Getters> vec=(Vector<Getters>)request.getAttribute("vec"); %>

<h1>Technical Panel</h1>



<center>
<table width="80" id="customers" id="Add">


<tr>
<form action="UpdateTechpanelDetails" method="Post">

<td>Employee ID</td>

<th><u>First Name</td>

<th><u>Last Name</u></th>
<th><u>Mobile No</u></th>

<th><u>Email ID</u></th>

<th><u>Skills</u></th>

</tr>

 <% 
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
 {%>

<tr>
 <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeID" value=" %=vec.elementAt(i).getEmployeeID()%>"/> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<%=vec.elementAt(i).getFirstName()%>"/> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="LastName" value="<%=vec.elementAt(i).getLastName()%>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="MobileNo" value="<%=vec.elementAt(i).getMobileNo()%>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="EmailID" value="<%=vec.elementAt(i).getEmailID()%>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="PanelPersonSkills" value="<%=vec.elementAt(i).getPanelPersonSkills()%>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>

}
</table>
<br><br>
<center><table>
<tr>
 <td><input type="submit"    value="Update"  /></td></form>
<td><form action="RetrievingTechpanelDetails"><input type="submit" name="button"  value="Back"></form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

## UpdateTechpanelDetails.java

```
package techpanel;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class UpdateTechpanelDetails extends HttpServlet {

    public UpdateTechpanelDetails() {
        super();
        }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



         String Eid = request.getParameter("EmployeeID");
         System.out.println(Eid);
        String FName = request.getParameter("FirstName");
        System.out.println(FName);
        String LName = request.getParameter("LastName");
        System.out.println(LName);
        String MNo = request.getParameter("MobileNo");
        System.out.println(MNo);
        String EID = request.getParameter("EmailID");
        System.out.println(EID);
        String Skills = request.getParameter("PanelPersonSkills");
        System.out.println(Skills);

        String msg=("Data Updated");
        Connection con=null; 
         PreparedStatement st=null;
       try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?user=root&password=kartheek");
         String sql = " UPDATE techpanel1.techpaneldetails SET EmployeeID=?,FirstName=?,LastName=?,MobileNo=?,EmailID=?,PanelPersonSkills=? WHERE EmployeeID=?";

        con.setAutoCommit(false);
          st = con.prepareStatement(sql);

         st.setString(1, Eid); 
         st.setString(2, FName ); 
         st.setString(3, LName); 
         st.setString(4, MNo ); 
         st.setString(5, EID );
         st.setString(6, Skills );
         st.setString(7, Eid); 



        st.executeUpdate();

        con.commit();
        request.setAttribute(".", msg);
         con.close();
         st.close();
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddingTechpanelDetails.jsp");
              rd.include(request, response);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }


    private int getInitParameter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

  }
```

## Main Problem

I have fetched the values from database in a vector `array(vec.elementAt(i).getEmployeeID(),vec.elementAt(i).getFirstName())` into a text boxes which is of editable `format(input type="text" name=EmployeeID value=<%=vec.elementAt(i).getEmployeeID()%>/>)`, and i want to update multiple records into database.but only first record is getting updated.. remaining or not updating. can any one help me please

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35614753 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4355046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using batch you can insert or update number of records try this code

```
 String sql = "update people set firstname=? , lastname=? where id=?";


PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
try{
    preparedStatement =
            connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Gary");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Larson");
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 123);

preparedStatement.addBatch();

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Stan");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Lee");
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 456);

preparedStatement.addBatch();

int[] affectedRecords = preparedStatement.executeBatch();

}finally {
    if(preparedStatement != null) {
        preparedStatement.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working.... Thank you.............If i want upload multiple file types, then what should i use ,..? I have used 'Part filename =request.getPart("name");'... it is working for one file...but for multiple files it is not working.... please help me...Thanks in advance

Comment: i have accepted.... can u please help me out for second one

Comment: Stack overflow  already has answer just check the link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932225/multiple-file-upload-using-single-servlet-request

Answer (score 2):

To get values of all textboxes use [request.getParameterValues('name')](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)), this will return all the values for elements with same 'name'
`String[] employeeID = request.getPrameterValues('EmployeeID')` will return all the text box values with name 'EmployeeID' into String array employeeID which you can iterate and get each values from textBox.

To update multiple rows, try using prepared statments [addBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch()) method, then to execute the batch statement using [executeBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) method

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply ... i have used  request.getParameterValues('name'),but it is fetching only last record values. here main problem is from jsp to servlet, i am able to get only one record, either first or last record only.if i use "getParameter"it is fetching first record.if i use "getParameterValues", it is fetching last record from jsp to servlet.

Comment: @P.Kartheek you will have to assign the value fo getParameterValues() into a String array. like `String[] employee|ID = request.getParameterValues("EmployeeID")`

Comment: Thank you....i have used it in same format and it is working fine....   Thank u very much

Comment: If i want upload multiple file types, then what should i use ,..? I have used 'Part filename =request.getPart("name");'... it is working for one file...but for multiple files it is not working.... please help me...Thanks in advance

Comment: If my answer was helpful kindly give an upvote/accept answer

Comment: how to upvote/accept answer..? this is for the first time i am using this.... can u please help me out

Comment: @P.Kartheek You can click the up arrow for up voting and click the tick button for approving answer. You have accepted the other answer you are allowed to accept only one answer but you are allowed to upvote multiple answers. Thanks.